# Php include with multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello I am having trouble accessing a multidimensional array that is on a separate php page.
Example
on index.php:

```
include 'scripts/test.php';
echo $test[1][1];
```

on test.php:

```
$test = array
(
array("One", "Two"),
array("Three", "Four")
);
```

Wanted Result:

```
Four
```

This works fine when I have the array on the same page as the echo, also the route is correct because this works fine when I'm using a normal array on the same test.php file.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: You included Wanted Result, but what is the Actual Result?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry this echo isn't loading anything at all. The page still loads but this echo does not actually display anything new.

Comment: you must be lost some kind of config, or other thing, I make files and test it and works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you turn error reporting on? Does the include work? The code itself should work so I guess your problem is the `include`

- Make sure the path is correct
- Make sure you don't mix up absolute and relative paths

You could also use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to be absolutely sure to include the right file:

```
<?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/scripts/test.php");
    doit();
?>
```

With your code your folder structure should look like this:

```
/scripts/test.php
/index.php
```

But first of all put this at the top of your `index.php`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```